# SUMIFS Excel Multi Criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to do use SUMIFS to calculate the total QTY changes for drawings with a material ID that Matches the Pipe Indent Numbers and ignore the ones that are NOT listed the piping indent numbers column. Below is what I have so far but I know the "=D:D" looks wrong.

I don't know how to reference all the numbers in the Pipe Indent Numbers List(D:) as each their own criteria, so that if the Material ID matches ANY of the Pipe Ident Numbers it will sum it.

I need help with this because my actual Pipe Ident Numbers column have about 100 other numbers not just the 5 shown.

Also not sure would I need to have the drawing number in the formula somewhere too? Maybe that's what I'm missing...

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"=D:D")
```

Any help would be amazing! Thanks :)

[image: r]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

if you want to compare row by row

```
=SUMPRODUCT(c2:c6*(b2:b6=d2:d6))
```

if you want to compare the value in column b with all values in column d (of you do not use Excel 365 press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formular)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(c2:c6*(b2:b6=TRANSPOSE(d2:d6)))
```

Best Regards
Chris

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. It would be correct ```=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C6*(B2:B6=TRANSPOSE(D2:D6)))``` entered as array formula

Comment: My formula works fine. SUMPRODUCT is an array formula. I do not see any sense to use transpose is this case.

Comment: If you do not transpose the range then it will go row by row comparison and D2:D6 is supposed to be a list of criteria to find anywhere in B:B not row by row.

Comment: OK. This was not my understanding of the question. You are right if the comparison should be to all values in range(D2:D6). Thanks basic and Scott

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,D2:D6))
```

One can use `D:D` but that would do many unneeded calculations.  One should limit the range to the dataset.